# Inheritance, NullPointerException concept of super()

Tags: java, inheritance

Base Class:

```
public class Base {
    private String baseMessage = "Hello!";

    public Base() {
        printMessage();
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println(baseMessage.toString());
    }
}
```

Derived Class:

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    private String derivedMessage = "World!";

    public Derived () {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    public void printMessage() {
        super.printMessage();
        System.out.println(derivedMessage.toString());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      new Base();
        new Derived();
    }
}
```

When I run

```
new Base();
```

I get the expected output:

```
Hello!
```

When I Run

```
new Derived();
```

I get

```
Hello!
Hello!
```

then NullPointerException. This seems a bit weird to me. I don't know why it's printing it out then throwing a nullpointerexception, rather straight up throwing it. Maybe it's Eclipse, I don't know.

What's the underlying concept here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you read this, read

- [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

The body of a child class constructor is compiled to something like this

```
public Derived () {
    super();
    initializeInstanceFields(); 
    // all instance fields are initialized either to their default value
    // or with their initialization expression
}
```

In other words, by the time the `Derived#printMessage()` is called because of polymorphism from the `super` constructor, the `Derived.derivedMessage` is still `null`.

---

Here's the step by step:

```
new Derived();
```

invokes the `Derived` constructor

```
public Derived () {
    super();
}
```

which invokes the `super` constructor

```
public Base() {
    printMessage();
}
```

Here, before the `printMessage()`, this class' instance fields are initialized, so `baseMessage` gets the value of `"Hello!"`. When `printMessage()` gets invoked, because `this` is a `Derived` object and `Derived` overrides the methods, its implementation is invoked.

```
@Override
public void printMessage() {
    super.printMessage();
    System.out.println(derivedMessage.toString());
}
```

This calls the `super` implementation

```
public void printMessage() {
    System.out.println(baseMessage.toString());
}
```

which prints

```
Hellow!
```

The method returns back to `Derived#printMessage` and attempts to invoke `toString()` on `derivedMessaged`, but, as I've explained earlier, the `derivedMessage` hasn't been initialized yet, so it is `null`. Dereferencing `null` causes `NullPointerException`.

**And this is why you don't invoke overridable methods from constructors.**

Comment: super() gets called, then it initializes all the fields?. How about the parent class? Does the fields get initialized there when super() is called, then derived class's fields get initialized?

Comment: @user121449 The `Base` class has its own call to `super()` (which invokes the `Object` constructor) and then initializes its own fields.

Comment: Second-question: why would Hello! get printed twice?

Comment: @user121449 It shouldn't. Save your code, recompile, and try again.

Comment: I think it's running the function from the base class twice, then going to the derived? But that doesn't make sense, since I never explicitly call the derived function

Comment: Because you override the printMessage() function it is then being called when the Base() constructor is being called.

Comment: @user121449 Are you sure you're not just seeing the output from `new Base()` from before? There should be only one `Hello!` printed for `new Derived();`.

Comment: @user121449 maybe you haven't commented out `new Base();`. That's why you are seeing `Hello!` printed twice.